# Why does android studio aligns xml code one line

Tags: xml, android-studio

Android studio aligns xml code one line automaticly... How do I can solve this problem?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just press enter at the end of the attribute that you have entered and then the next one will begin in the next line. The thing is that it doesn’t make a difference, the code is the same when it reaches the compiler. 
I never tried to change a setting because it doesn’t make a difference whether the individual attributes are on the same line. However, just press enter at the end of each attribute.